# Gradle fails sync when realm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0 added to Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, realm

First of all, as this is my first question, I'd like to say hallo to all of you. This community is awesome and answers I'm finding here help me every time I'm coding. Not this time.

So, I'm writing small app for Android and time has come to add database layer. To do that I've gone through [realm installation guide](https://realm.io/news/android-installation-change/) and added to my projects *build.gradle* line:

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
```

and then following line to my app module *build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

but here my problems started. Before adding these two lines gradle was syncing and building project successfully, but after that two lines being added it fails to sync with error message:

> Error:Could not find property 'options' on task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJack'.

Event log shows:

> 17:24:48 Gradle sync started
>   17:24:50 Gradle sync failed: Could not find property 'options' on task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJack'.
>            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

I've tried *./gradlew clean* but it didn't change anything, neither did deleting *.gradle* in my home directory and letting Android Studio handle dependencies from scratch.

Here's my project's *build.gradle*:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my app module's *build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' //
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    //compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    //buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0-rc4"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "agh.jitp2.quizzy"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.4.1'
    testCompile 'org.mutabilitydetector:MutabilityDetector:0.9.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

Do you have any hints for me what needs to be done to make this project being built?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

EDIT:
@cricket_007: above is al I get in messages window and Event log. Gradle Console is empty. But when I run *build* on app module *build.gradle* with --info flag I get following output:

> [...]
>     Starting Build
>     Settings evaluated using settings file 'C:_Dev_Repos\AGH\Quizzy\settings.gradle'.
>     Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:_Dev_Repos\AGH\Quizzy\build.gradle'.
>     Included projects: [root project 'Quizzy', project ':app']
>     Evaluating root project 'Quizzy' using build file 'C:_Dev_Repos\AGH\Quizzy\build.gradle'.
>     Evaluating project ':app' using build file 'C:_Dev_Repos\AGH\Quizzy\app\build.gradle'.
>     Creating configuration compile
>     Creating configuration apk
>     Creating configuration provided
>     Creating configuration wearApp
>     Creating configuration androidTestCompile
>     Creating configuration androidTestApk
>     Creating configuration androidTestProvided
>     Creating configuration androidTestWearApp
>     Creating configuration testCompile
>     Creating configuration testApk
>     Creating configuration testProvided
>     Creating configuration testWearApp
>     Creating configuration debugCompile
>     Creating configuration debugApk
>     Creating configuration debugProvided
>     Creating configuration debugWearApp
>     Creating configuration testDebugCompile
>     Creating configuration testDebugApk
>     Creating configuration testDebugProvided
>     Creating configuration testDebugWearApp
>     Creating configuration releaseCompile
>     Creating configuration releaseApk
>     Creating configuration releaseProvided
>     Creating configuration releaseWearApp
>     Creating configuration testReleaseCompile
>     Creating configuration testReleaseApk
>     Creating configuration testReleaseProvided
>     Creating configuration testReleaseWearApp
>     Parsing the SDK, no caching allowed
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\build-tools\23.0.3\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\docs\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\extras\android\m2repository\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\extras\google\m2repository\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\extras\google\usb_driver\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\platforms\android-23\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\platforms\android-N\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\sources\android-23\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\package.xml
>     Parsing C:_Dev\Android\SDK\tools\package.xml
>     Incremental Java compilation disabled in variant debug as you are using an incompatible plugin
>     Not using incremental javac compilation.
>     Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
>     Incremental Java compilation disabled in variant debugUnitTest as you are using an incompatible plugin
>     Not using incremental javac compilation.
>     Incremental Java compilation disabled in variant release as you are using an incompatible plugin
>     Not using incremental javac compilation.
>     Incremental Java compilation disabled in variant releaseUnitTest as you are using an incompatible plugin
>     Not using incremental javac compilation.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     > Could not find property 'options' on task   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJack'.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
>
>   BUILD FAILED

Comment: Can you show the full Gradle output, not only the final error message?

Comment: The problem is the Jack compiler, not Realm, by the way. At least not directly. Realm might not support it yet

Comment: For reference, here is a similar issue for the Butterknife library.  https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/571

Comment: As @cricket found, JACK cannot compile realm as noted [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/571) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204065#c8).  

To use realm I had to disable jack in app's _build.gradle_. And also because of disabling jack, I had to refactor every place in code I was using java 1.8 lambdas.

Comment: You're welcome to answer below with your findings instead of using a comment

Comment: Plus, you can use the retrolamba library if you would like to keep them

Comment: You can also use Retrolambda plugin to use Lambda Expressions even with java 1.7 (without JACK)

Answer (score 1):

```
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
```

JACK currently does not support annotation processing (used to generate proxies in Realm), but it also doesn't generate *class* files which Realm uses with Javassist (bytecode manipulation) through the Realm-Transformer which turns all field access into proxy method calls.

It's for the sake of removing mandatory getter/setters, actually. But with that update, also came the ability to use interfaces on Realm Objects, so it's a kinda important step.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue when trying to use Realm, so what I did was just to rely on [retro-lambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda). That worked for me.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
     mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
     classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
  }
}

// Required because retrolambda is on maven central
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```